# WPF how to put label in the middle of circle

Tags: wpf, geometry, textblock

I have `WPF` application and `Circle ProgressBar`:

```
<Grid>
        <Path x:Name="pathRoot" Stroke="{Binding SegmentColor, ElementName=userControl}"
              StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness, ElementName=userControl}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure x:Name="pathFigure">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <ArcSegment x:Name="arcSegment" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>

public partial class CircularProgressBar : UserControl
    {
        public CircularProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Angle = (Percentage * 360) / 100;
            RenderArc();
        }

    public int Radius
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush SegmentColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(SegmentColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SegmentColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public int StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Percentage
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PercentageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PercentageProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Angle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Percentage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PercentageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Percentage", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(65d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPercentageChanged)));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StrokeThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(5));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SegmentColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SegmentColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SegmentColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(60, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(120d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnPercentageChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        CircularProgressBar circle = sender as CircularProgressBar;
        circle.Angle = (circle.Percentage * 360) / 100;
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        CircularProgressBar circle = sender as CircularProgressBar;
        circle.RenderArc();
    }

    public void RenderArc()
    {
        Point startPoint = new Point(Radius, 0);
        Point endPoint = ComputeCartesianCoordinate(Angle, Radius);
        endPoint.X += Radius;
        endPoint.Y += Radius;

        pathRoot.Width = Radius * 2 + StrokeThickness;
        pathRoot.Height = Radius * 2 + StrokeThickness;
        pathRoot.Margin = new Thickness(StrokeThickness, StrokeThickness, 0, 0);

        bool largeArc = Angle > 180.0;

        Size outerArcSize = new Size(Radius, Radius);

        pathFigure.StartPoint = startPoint;

        if (startPoint.X == Math.Round(endPoint.X) && startPoint.Y == Math.Round(endPoint.Y))
            endPoint.X -= 0.01;

        arcSegment.Point = endPoint;
        arcSegment.Size = outerArcSize;
        arcSegment.IsLargeArc = largeArc;
    }

    private Point ComputeCartesianCoordinate(double angle, double radius)
    {
        // convert to radians
        double angleRad = (Math.PI / 180.0) * (angle - 90);

        double x = radius * Math.Cos(angleRad);
        double y = radius * Math.Sin(angleRad);

        return new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

This is my `XAML` with my `CircleProgressBar`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="54,507,54,75" Grid.Column="1" Height="138">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="153" Width="155">
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
         SegmentColor="#FF878889" StrokeThickness="10" Percentage="100" />
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Percentage="33" SegmentColor="#FF5591E8" StrokeThickness="10"  />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Inside this controller i locate `Label` that show my the `ProgressBar` percentage but this label is not all the time in the middle on the `circle`

```
    <Label Name="lblCircleProgress" Content="0%" Margin="116,561,100,127" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
```

So my question is how to implement this label to became in the middle of my `Circle` all the time after the percentage changing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your grid - and place everything inside it.

This way everything will center horizontally and vertically within the same visual context.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="153" Width="155">
    <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                         SegmentColor="#FF878889" StrokeThickness="10" Percentage="100" />
    <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                         SegmentColor="#FF5591E8" StrokeThickness="10" Percentage="33" />            
    <Label Name="lblCircleProgress" Content="0%" Foreground="White" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it in the Grid also, delete those margin and set HorizontalAlignment to Center. I see you already have the VerticalAlignment set, so that should work and you should see it in the center of the Grid, and taking into consideration that your CircularProgressBar is inside the Grid too, it should look as expected.